# Drawing with GDI and text with Qt

Tags: qt, mfc, winapi

Hi I have an existing MFC application which draws some shape on screen, Now A Qt plug in is being developed whose one job is to add some text in the MFC drawing.
We are using Qt to draw the text in bitmap and then bitblting that on screen so that MFC Cview shows both together.
But when we are trying to print(usign Qprinter for text) Text goes on different document and drawing goes on different.
Also text bitmap if printed to pdf is not scalable because it is bitmap.
How you guys suggest should be the best way of doing this?

BR,
Harris

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really *have* to use Qt for this, it'll almost certainly be easier to draw the text with MFC (TextOut or DrawText).

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to get it working on screen, drawing the same thing on a printer DC should also work. Where is the difference in the drawing routines? Do you really need two routines?